# Laravel query - grouping results in a range of dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, eloquent

I have a table from which I'd like to pull a list of `object_id` that satisfy condition:

- `extended_data` starts with "Text1" or "Text2",
- time difference between records in table containing "Text1" and "Text2" for a given `object_id` is less than 2 seconds.
  I'm sending code written so far and an example table with selected records that meet condition. As a result, the query for example should return [3, 7].
  How should I expand code to get solution?

| id | object_id | extended_data | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Text1 lorem | 12.01.2023 11:01:22 |
| 2 | 2 | Text2 lorem | 12.01.2023 11:02:25 |
| **3** | **3** | **Text1 lorem** | **12.01.2023 11:03:04** |
| **4** | **3** | **Text2 lorem** | **12.01.2023 11:03:05** |
| 5 | 4 | Lorem | 12.01.2023 11:05:44 |
| 6 | 5 | Text1 ipsum | 12.01.2023 11:05:45 |
| 7 | null | ipsum | 12.01.2023 11:06:23 |
| 8 | 6 | Text1 ipsum | 12.01.2023 11:08:21 |
| 9 | 6 | Text2 ipsum | 12.01.2023 11:08:32 |
| **10** | **7** | **Text1 ipsum** | **12.01.2023 11:09:12** |
| 11 | 7 | ipsum | 12.01.2023 11:09:12 |
| **12** | **7** | **Text2 ipsum** | **12.01.2023 11:09:12** |

```
$logs = Logs::whereNotNull('object_id')->get();

$filtered = $logs->filter(function (Logs $log) {
    return str_starts_with($log->extended_data, "Text1") || str_starts_with($log->extended_data, "Text2");
})->values();

foreach ($filtered as $index => $log) {
    $unset = false;
    $actualTimestamp = strtotime($log->timestamp);

    if ($index > 0) {
        $previousTimestamp = strtotime($filtered[$index - 1]->timestamp);
        $differenceInSeconds = $actualTimestamp - $previousTimestamp;
        if ($differenceInSeconds > 2) {
            $unset = true;
        }
    }

    if (count($filtered) - 1 > $index) {
        $nextTimestamp = strtotime($filtered[$index + 1]->timestamp);
        $differenceInSeconds = $nextTimestamp - $actualTimestamp;
        if ($differenceInSeconds > 2) {
            $unset = true;
        }
    }

    if ($unset) {
        $log->unset = true;
    }
}

foreach ($filtered as $index => $log) {
    if (isset($log->unset) && $log->unset) {
        unset($filtered[$index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this assuming that the timestamp column contains a valid datetime/timestamp (`2023-01-12 11:01:22`) and not the string format (`12.01.2023 11:01:22`) you have included in your sample data.

```
SELECT l1.object_id
FROM logs l1
JOIN logs l2
    ON l1.object_id = l2.object_id
    AND l2.extended_data LIKE 'Text2%'
    AND l2.timestamp BETWEEN l1.timestamp AND l1.timestamp + INTERVAL 2 SECOND
WHERE l1.extended_data LIKE 'Text1%'
```

And, assuming the text of this query is static, to run it you can just do -

```
$logs = DB::select("
SELECT l1.object_id
FROM logs l1
JOIN logs l2
    ON l1.object_id = l2.object_id
    AND l2.extended_data LIKE 'Text2%'
    AND l2.timestamp BETWEEN l1.timestamp AND l1.timestamp + INTERVAL 2 SECOND
WHERE l1.extended_data LIKE 'Text1%'
");
```

There would be no benefit in building up this query using Query Builder.